# C# double.ToString() max number of digits and trailing zeros

Tags: c#, string, format

How to convert a `double` into a `string` with 6 max number of digits and remove trailing zeros?

I want to have :

```
2.123456123 -> "2.123456"
0.0000012 -> "0.000001"   (and not "1.2e-6")
12.45 -> "12.45"   (and not "12.450000")
36 -> "36"   (and not "36.000000")
```

using `string.Format("{0:F6"}, value)` output trailing zeros and `string.Format("{0:G6"}, value)` will not fit the second example.

Is it ok to use `value.ToString("0.######)`?

Is there an equivalent way to do with `string.Format()`?

Comment: Yes, it is OK to use `value.ToString("0.######")`. It will use the current culture of the current thread, for example when deciding what string (like `.`) to use for the decimal point. The equivalent with `string.Format` is simply: `string.Format("My number {0:0.######} looks good.", value)` If you want culture-independence, try `value.ToString("0.######", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` respectively `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "My number {0:0.######} looks good.", value)`.

Comment: [`#`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD) is made specifically for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *is* okay to use `value.ToString("0.######")`. However, you should consider another thing: `double` is not a decimal (base 10) number. You should not rely on the decimal representation of the number to be anything reasonable - plenty of normal decimal base 10 numbers require infinite decimal expansion in base 2.

If you do care about the decimal representation, it *might* be a better idea to use `decimal` instead - it's also a floating point number, but in base 10.

And in either case, this involves rounding - that might or might not be what you want.

Comment: In this particular case with `double`, precision starts to be a problem when the amount (its absolute value) exceeds one billion. For example `1000000000.654321` will not have full precision when formatted to a string in this way (string becomes `"1000000000.65432"`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is indeed because the natural rounding of double is imprecise in the last decimals that we need to round the values when writing them to a file. We noticed that depending on the machine used, the natural rounding will not be the same (around 1e-14 / 1e-15 precision).

Answer (score 0):

tokens is a ViewModel with Price string property:

```
foreach (var item in tokens)
{
  item.Price = double.Parse(item.Price).ToString("#,0");
}

// 123456 => 123,456
```